# Product of almost surely converging and converging in probability random variables

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

Suppose $0 \leq X_n \xrightarrow{P} X$ and $0 \leq Y_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$ where $|X| < \infty$ almost surely.

I'm interested in whether $X_nY_n \xrightarrow{a.s.} 0$

It would suffice to show that $$A \equiv \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n\ge N} \{X_nY_n \ge \epsilon\}$$ is a null set $\forall \epsilon > 0$.  Obviously $Y_n(\omega) < \epsilon \quad \forall n\ge M(\omega)$ for a.e. $\omega$ so that

$\omega \in \bigcap_{N=1}^\infty \bigcup_{n\ge N} \{X_n(\omega) \ge 1\}$ for a.e. $\omega \in A$.  But this proves nothing I think, so I really don't know how to proceed (or if it's even true).  Please help me if you can.  Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not true. Let $X_n$ be independent random variables such that $P(X_n=0)=1-\frac 1 n$ and $P(X_n=n^{2})=\frac  1n$. Let $Y_n=\frac  1n$. Then $Y_n \to 0$ almost surely and $P(|X_n| >\epsilon) \leq \frac  1n \to 0$ for any $\epsilon$. But $\sum P(X_n=n^{2}) =\infty$ and Borel Cantelli Lemma shows that $X_n =n^{2}$ infinitely often with probability $1$. Hence $P(X_nY_n \to 0)=0$!